# Magento2 new grid system and why exists old style GRIG

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent

Magento2 has new grid system throught ui component example:

> app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml

And why exists old style for grid like:

> app/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Grid.php

Guys any fresh ideas?